# Doctrine Orm - Searching embedded associations

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I have an Asset Entity that uses an embedded association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Asset
{

....

    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="Money\Money")
     */
   private $code;
```

I want to search this class and my first instinct was to do something like this:

```
public function findOneByCurrencyCode(string $currencyCode)
{
    $qb = $this->assetRepository->createQueryBuilder('asset');
    $qb->innerJoin('asset.code', 'code')
        ->where('code.currency = :currency')
        ->setParameter('currency', $currencyCode);

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    return $result;
}
```

This, however, returns the following:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 65 near 'code WHERE code.currency': Error: 
Class Domain\Asset\Asset has no association named code
```

How do you search embedded classes?

EDIT:

I can get a result by doing something like this, however, this I feel is a hack:

```
    $query = "SELECT * from asset where code_currency='BTC';";
    $statement = $this->objectManager->getConnection()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Embedded associations" does NOT exist**. So, **you doesn't need JOINS**.

An embedded is part of your entity along with the others properties.

You have to do something like that:

```php
SELECT u
FROM User u
WHERE u.address.city
```

(In this query, your entity is **User**, your embedded is **Address** and **city* is the property of your
embedded).

It's pretty good explained in Doctrine documentation:
[Doctrine embeddables](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/embeddables.html)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I understand them a lot better today than I did then and this serves as a good outline for others.

Answer (score 6):

I tried a bunch of different things and managed to get the answer:

```
    $qb = $this->assetRepository->createQueryBuilder('asset');
    $qb->where('asset.code.currency = :currency')
        ->setParameter('currency', $currencyCode);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    return $result;
```

Turns out no inner join is required. Not sure why and perhaps someone can answer this in time, however the above appears to work with embedded objects

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I wouldn't ever have thought that I could do `class.property.propertyOfProperty`-style checks, thank you for this answer :)